# android in virtualbox no wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, android

I have installed the last Android (android-x86_64-6.0-rc2) on VirtualBox. Everything is OK, internet too, but I have a problem with a game (March of Empire): It doesn't update because it wants WiFi on. I said I could navigate but I cannot see the WiFi on.

I configured the LAN of VirtualBox in two ways: NAT and BRIDGE.

The Internet is OK, but WiFi always off.

So I need to simulate WiFi on. How can I do that?

Comment: I want to know if this section is wrong too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27463792/2112755